# Does django-saml2-auth support share tokens between service providers (SPs)?

Tags: django, saml, django-saml2-auth

First of all, SAML noob here.

Does django-saml2-auth support tokens being shared between Service Providers (SPs)? Eg. Service provider A can perform an **API** request with a SAML token (issued by same IdP) to Service provider B, so the request is authenticated automatically (without needing to redirect the browser to IdP)?

Some code is better than no code, but I am not familiar with the plugin so I am just gonna make up some imaginary settings that specified in both service providers:

```
MUTUAL_AGREED_IdP = 'http://idp.example.com'
```

By the way, is this called 'federation'? I read the wiki about SAML federation, it mentions about 2 different IdPs to form a federation, but in my example is just one IdP.